# Version 4.00b of tkz-euclide -- remove "cm"

Tags: tkz-euclide

Some of my pictures do no longer compile with version 4.00b of package [`tkz-euclide`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide).

The [announcement](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.2096.1641412362.10251.ctan-ann@ctan.org) of the new version (2022-Jan-5) of `tkz-euclide` says:

> Some new macros have appeared, others (secondary) have disappeared.
> The only important constraint to transfer the code from version 3 to 4
> is to remove the unit "cm".

I probably have hundreds of occurences of "cm" in my files. What is the suggested way to handle this? To which unit should "cm" be converted to? Can I use "mm" instead?
In the first go I took the "remove" literally and just eliminated it, but this changes the pictures.

Please also look at the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){M1}
\tkzDefPoint(120:5){X}
\tkzDefPoint(120:3){M2}
\tkzDefPoint(45:4){P}
\tkzInterLC(P,M1)(M1,X)\tkzGetPoints{N1}{F1}
\tkzInterLC(P,M2)(M2,X)\tkzGetPoints{N2}{F2}
\tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll,size=.9cm](F2,X,F1)
\tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll,size=.9cm](N2,X,N1)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Removing the two occurences of `cm` gives a different picture. I hope you can reproduce this -- inclusion of .pdfs is unfortunately not supported here.

Comment: just delete "cm". The unit as in `TikZ` is now by default the 'cm'. The most affected macros are those concerning circles with definitions, drawing or intersections. Another macro is `tkzCalcLength`, it is no longer necessary to put [cm]. Logically the code compiles but the distances are wrong. If you need I can send you the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

An example with some `cm`. The code compiles but in your .log file you will see :

```
Missing character: There is no c ("63) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no m ("6D) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no c ("63) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no m ("6D) in font nullfont!
```

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
  
\tkzSetUpColors[background=white,text=teal]  
\tkzSetUpPoint[size=2,color=teal]
\tkzSetUpLine[thin,color=teal]
\tkzSetUpCompass[color=brown,ultra thin,/tkzcompass/delta=10]
\tikzset{label style/.append style={color=teal}}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[rotate=28]
  \tkzDefPoint(4,0){A} \tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}  \tkzDefPoint(1.5,4){C}
  \tkzDrawLines(B,A B,C)
  \tkzFillAngle[fill=teal!30,size=1](A,B,C)
  \tkzDefPointWith[linear normed,K=2](B,A) \tkzGetPoint{I}
  \tkzDefPointWith[linear normed,K=2](B,C) \tkzGetPoint{J}
  \tkzDrawArc(B,I)(J)
  \tkzCompass(I,J)
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,I,J) 
  \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,I,J)
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
  \tkzDefPoint(5,0){B'}
  \tkzDefPoint(9,0){A'}
  \tkzDrawLine(B',A')
  \tkzDuplicateSegment(B,I)(B',A')  \tkzGetPoint{I'} 
  \tkzDrawArc[angles](B',I')(0,80)
  \tkzCalcLength[cm](I,J)  \tkzGetLength{dIJ}
  \tkzCalcLength[cm](B,I)  \tkzGetLength{dBI} 
  \tkzDrawArc[arc,R](I',\dIJ)(100,120)
  \tkzInterCC[R](B',\dBI cm)(I',\dIJ cm)\tkzGetPoints{J'}{K}  
  \tkzDrawLine[add = 0 and 1](B',J')
  \tkzFillAngle[fill=teal!30,size=1cm](A',B',J')
  \tkzDrawPoints(A',B',I',J')
  \tkzLabelPoints(A',B',I',J')
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now the code should be written like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
  
\tkzSetUpColors[background=white,text=teal]  
\tkzSetUpPoint[size=2,color=teal]
\tkzSetUpLine[thin,color=teal]
\tkzSetUpCompass[color=brown,ultra thin,/tkzcompass/delta=10]
\tikzset{label style/.append style={color=teal}}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[rotate=28]
  \tkzDefPoint(4,0){A} \tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}  \tkzDefPoint(1.5,4){C}
  \tkzDrawLines(B,A B,C)
  \tkzFillAngle[fill=teal!30,size=1](A,B,C)
  \tkzDefPointWith[linear normed,K=2](B,A) \tkzGetPoint{I}
  \tkzDefPointWith[linear normed,K=2](B,C) \tkzGetPoint{J}
  \tkzDrawArc(B,I)(J)
  \tkzCompass(I,J)
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,I,J) 
  \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,I,J)
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
  \tkzDefPoint(5,0){B'}
  \tkzDefPoint(9,0){A'}
  \tkzDrawLine(B',A')
  \tkzDuplicateSegment(B,I)(B',A')  \tkzGetPoint{I'} 
  \tkzDrawArc[angles](B',I')(0,80)
  \tkzCalcLength(I,J)  \tkzGetLength{dIJ}
  \tkzCalcLength(B,I)  \tkzGetLength{dBI} 
  \tkzDrawArc[arc,R](I',\dIJ)(100,120)
  \tkzInterCC[R](B',\dBI)(I',\dIJ)\tkzGetPoints{J'}{K}  
  \tkzDrawLine[add = 0 and 1](B',J')
  \tkzFillAngle[fill=teal!30,size=1](A',B',J')
  \tkzDrawPoints(A',B',I',J')
  \tkzLabelPoints(A',B',I',J')
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With your MWE if you keep "cm" then you have an error :

> ! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `c' or` cm' (in
> '.9cmcm-2.5\pgflinewidth ').

Without "cm"

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){M1}
\tkzDefPoint(120:5){X}
\tkzDefPoint(120:3){M2}
\tkzDefPoint(45:4){P}
\tkzInterLC(P,M1)(M1,X)\tkzGetPoints{N1}{F1}
\tkzInterLC(P,M2)(M2,X)\tkzGetPoints{N2}{F2}
\tkzDrawPoints(M1,M2,X,P,N1,N2,F1,F2)
\tkzLabelPoints(M1,M2,X,P,N1,N2,F1,F2)
\tkzDrawSegments(P,M1 P,F2 X,F1 X,F2 N1,F1 X,N1 X,N2)
\tkzDrawCircles(M1,X M2,X)
\tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll,size=.9](F2,X,F1)
\tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll,size=.9](N2,X,N1)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please look at the MWE above.